# Trying to open *.hdf5 file in docker but always get error message = 'Is a directory'

Tags: python, docker

I have the script **predict** that runs the following command:

```
# run predictions
DOCKER_RUN="docker run
  --entrypoint entrypoints/entrypoint.predict.cpu.sh \
  -v "$IMAGE_SOURCE":/src/$BASENAME_IS
  -v "$WEIGHTS_FILE":/weights.hdf5
  $DOCKER_IMAGE $BASE_MODEL_NAME /weights.hdf5 /src/$BASENAME_IS"

eval $DOCKER_RUN
```

I'm using Mac and when I try to run the following command:

```
/predict  --docker-image nima-cpu --base-model-name MobileNet --weights-file $(pwd)/models/MobileNet/weights_mobilenet_technical_0.11.hdf5 --image-source $(pwd)/src/tests/test_images/42039.jpg
```

**The output I'm getting**

```
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 88, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file read failed: time = Sun Oct 18 09:18:54 2020
, filename = '/weights.hdf5', file descriptor = 3, errno = 21, error message = 'Is a directory', buf = 0x7fff466d1fd0, total read size = 8, bytes this sub-read = 8, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 0)
```

But it's a file with prediction. Not a directory.
Please, help me resolve the issue. Why can't I open that weights.hdf5 file?

Comment: `But it's a file` => You have to find out why you think it is a file when docker thinks it is not (spoiler alert: there are 99.9999999% chances docker is right). There is absolutely no debugging info in your question that could help someone to answer without making wild guesses. You should write out/log the value of `$WEIGHTS_FILE` to check your mount option (even the full `docker run` command). My guess is that `$(pwd)` contains spaces, special chars or whatever and since you did not quote your path (which you should always do as a good practice), it is not received correctly on the other end

Comment: I just thought adding the whole log would be cumbersome. I will definitely try to take out all the spaces and try again.
Would you help me if I posted the whole log(in case the option above won't work)?

UPD: It did not work :(

Comment: I have no idea if I will directly help you. But since your question is at risk of being closed if it does not provide enough debugging details, you put yourself in a situation where no one will be able to help you. enough does not mean a plethora. Just included the needed information, ideally an [mcve](/help/mcve)